# WPF Combobox can't find SelectedValue in ItemSource because of different case

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox that is meant to show a list of installed printers.  My view model's `Printer` property is predefined with a particular printer path string as described below.  However, the ComboBox is not being set to the predefined value initially.  It appears this is caused by the predefined value being in a different case than the value in the installed printers list.

I have created a `PrinterViewModel` class that looks like:

```
public class PrinterViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name of the printer (e.g. 'My Printer on PrinterServer')
    public string Id { get; set; } // Path of the printer (e.g. '\\PrinterServer\My Printer')
}
```

The ComboBox looks like:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Printer, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Where `Printers` is an `ObservableCollection<PrinterViewModel>` property and `Printer` is a string property that should be populated by `Id`.

For example, if my predefined value for `Printer` is '\printerserver\My Printer', but the list of installed printers contains '\PrinterServer\MyPrinter' these do not match because of different case and the `SelectedValue` is not applied in my ComboBox.

Is there a way to compare the provided `SelectedValue` with the items in the `ItemSource` and ignore case?

Comment: Equality of two PrinterViewModel is not based on the value of either Name nor Id.  You need to overide equals.

Comment: I would store the Id value as either all uppercase or all lowercase to ensure comparisms are made correctly.

Comment: @Blam - In this case I am not comparing two PrinterViewModel's because I am working with SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem.  Instead I am actually comparing the Id of each PrinterViewModel.

Comment: Would it work to use `IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="false"`? It's typically used for searching the ComboBox when the user types their own text, but I'm not sure if it will work on the Value comparsim or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your `Printer` property always hold the lower-case `Id`, then use a converter in your `SelectedValue` binding:

```
// Don't forget to add support for INotifyPropertyChanged
private string printer;
public string Printer
{
    get { return printer; }
    set { printer = value == null ? null : value.ToLower(); }
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Printer, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={local:ToLowerConverter}}"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this.  Instead of using a Converter, I simply use ToLower() on each of the installed printers when I generate the list of PrinterViewModel's to be used as ItemSource.  I was originally concerned that the PrinterSettings.PrinterName property of a PrintDocument is case sensitive, but it isn't.